# Communicating from one jsp to another via servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have 2 jsp pages. A main page and a form page. The main page has a grid (extjs framework) and when I click on a row it opens my form jsp page. What I want to achieve is, once the form is submitted, I want my main page to refresh its grid in order to show the new data that was submitted from the form. Note that the form page is a new window. **They both co-exist** in different browser windows (the user sees both at the same time).

One way I thought of doing this is via server sent events. After the form submit, I send an ajax request to the servlet from the form.jsp and it was supposed to respond with an event-stream listened by my main.jsp but it doesn't seem to work. When I try to create the EventSource object it gives me the error:

`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/javascript") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

The error seems to appear in my doctype declaration:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

I'm not really sure why this is happening. Any help on that would be appreciated.

Regardless of the method I tried to implement, is there a better way of doing this? Or a fix for the server sent events method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this `window.opener.location.reload(true)` on form submission.  'true' if you wand to reload this page completely from the server.

In case you don't want to refresh the whole page then you can follow the below steps.

- create a method on main page with code to refresh your grid. `function refreshGrid()`.
- call this method from the opened page using the opener reference.
  `window.opener.refreshGrid()`.

Hope this help.

Comment: The form gets submitted from page A and I want to send an event to page B. I do not see how this helps. Also I do not want my page to reload I want it to receive an asynchronous response.

Comment: I assumed page B opens page A as a new page on the browser. So B become an opener for page A, Parent.  then You can do the above on javascript on page A when you want to refresh page B.

Comment: You are right I edited my post to emphasize on that.

Comment: So the solution provided should work.  Not through seperate Servlet but completely on the client side.

Comment: As I said, I do not want to reload the page. I just want to refresh some of its data, similar to when I receive a response from an ajax request.

Comment: then you can do this. You can write a function `refreshGrid()` on main page, write code to refresh the grid in this method and call this method from the opened page when the form is submitted before closing. Make sure that they are both in same domain. `window.opener.refreshGrid()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73665/discussion-between-jafar-ali-and-konstantine).

Comment: Well I ended up using the way suggested above (creating a function in the window object) although it is a bit sloppy. It solves the problem in question though so I cannot say it is not an answer.